# Eclipse unable to import File object FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp

I am new for Importing file using scanner line by line reader .When i have import file it's working correctly , but some other system(i.e. colleague system) same project and same database connection while importing file error like **Java.io.FileNotfoundException** local drive fake path directory (e.g: "c:\fake path\db.sql").

```
public boolean checkfile(String dbfile){
   File obj = new File(dbfile)
   Scanner scr = new Scanner(obj );
   try{
    while(scr .hasNext()){
     String scr_line = scr.nextLine();
     System.out.println(scr_line );
    }
   }catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.tostring());
   }
 }
```

Above code `File obj = new File(dbFile)` this line error  message showing like `Java.io.FileNotFoundException` local drive fake path directory . can any please help me where i have done mistake above this code .

Answer (score 0):

**1 ,** File you try read  is not available in your colleague system or where you run this java program

**2 ,** check this file "c:\fake path\db.sql" is available or not in where you run this java program

**3 ,** When you run the program make sure you are sending the file path based on the Environment(Windows,unix etc.....)

**4 ,** check  File availability first

```
try
{
File f = new File("c:\fake path\db.sql");
if(f.exists())
   {
        //read the file
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
// do some work
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply me. i have  tried like that my system working , but my colleague system still file not found exception error message showing. can you briefly explain to me because i am new for this type of program .

Comment: hi, i am running my any local drive importing db.sql file , its working my system , but my colleague sysytem same error like "c:\fake path directory \db.sql"  message showing . its urgent requirement let me soon.

Comment: I have tried like getting root path local directory  like  D\software\eclipse\eclipse . and File get Absolute path is dynamic path location . i cannot get any clear idea still now total time waste. can any one let me know .

Comment: Did you checked the file available or not in your colleague system manually?                                                                   if yes which operating system you are using (windows or what)      Please reply me I will do help as much as can.

Comment: in your second comment you have mentioned this as file path "c:\fake path directory \db.sql" there is a space in file name so make sure file name is correct.

Comment: I am uploading  dynamic file path . so when i upload my file  file not found exception  local drive \fake path\directory\db.sql showing error message.

Comment: please tell me the operating system name and you are trying this in using servlets or jsp or normal(core) java.give clear details about your problem .

Comment: OS windows 7 ultimate , IE 7 , using jsp , class java .here java code is public boolean checkfile(String dbfile){
   File obj = new File(dbfile)
   Scanner scr = new Scanner(obj );
   try{
    while(scr .hasNext()){
     String scr_line = scr.nextLine();
     System.out.println(scr_line );
    }
   }catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.tostring());
   } this code working my system but my colleague system file not found exception error message showing.
 }

Comment: print the file path in console something will come like this"c:\sql.txt"   and find that path in where you run the program  there file is not available .Thats it.

Comment: hi, I am find my root path like D:\newsoftware\eclipse\eclipse , but my db.sql file path is dynamic local drive like e.g c:\file\db.sql ,how i can both root path and virtual path make it single path. any other approach.

Comment: so dynamic path is c:\file\db.sql and root path is  D:\newsoftware\eclipse\eclipse  copy the db.sql file in c:\file this location

Comment: i am using input type file in jsp page and javascript method like function check(){var file = document.getElementById("dbfile").value ;alert(file);}my system correct path out put like c:/document, but my colleague system c:/fakepath/db.sql . let me know as soon as possible how i can rectify this problem .i don't have any idea.

Comment: before running program did you check file in this path c:\file\db.sql of you colleague system.

Comment: its dynamic path , any file importing like .sql extension .

Comment: thats right when you get filenotfoundexception check whether that file is available or not in that location.

Comment: yes its always available in local system  . But different name file .

Comment: so file is not available it brings filenotfoundexception, Now can make dbfilename and filename in local system same.Changing local system  filename as filename from DB will be good idea. Thank you.

Comment: i am importing i.e. uploading db.sql file in jsp page , javascript error message showing fake path. code like function ch(){ var file = document.getElementById("file").value;}